# iOS - does App Store require iPad screenshots for upgraded iPhone app

Tags: ios, mobile, app-store

Not sure if the App Store listing rules have changed, but I am planning on submitting a new app to the iOS App store soon.  One of the previous versions of the app had the 'Universal' build type marked in XCode (done by another developer) and for the newer release, I only wanted to support iPhone.  Is it still possible to submit the app for review like this?  I don't want to go through the extra effort of taking iPad screenshots if I don't have to.

Comment: If you have ever released a Universal version of your app then you cannot revert to an iPhone only app. Your binary upload will fail if you try to submit an iPhone only build

Comment: @Paulw11 ok thanks, it looks like the rule has not changed then :(